# Including PHP extension

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use chrome logger to debug PHP.

I added chrome logger to my browser:
https://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger

I added ChromePhp.php to the build directory in my project which is currently being hosted on vagrant.

[image]

Now I am trying to simply include this file and do a few calls in y base.blade.php (esentially a master template):

```
<?php
    include '$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/build/ChromePhp.php';
    ChromePhp::log('Hello console!');
    ChromePhp::log($_SERVER);
    ChromePhp::warn('something went wrong!');
?>
```

I get the error:

ErrorException in 07bbfec098846578d2c405a4d52ca58d line 47:
include($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/build/ChromePhp.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (View: /var/www/build/resources/views/base.blade.php) (View: /var/www/build/resources/views/base.blade.php)

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Use double quotes `"` (variables inside these are evaluated, not inside single quotes) and put `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` inside brackets like so: `{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}`. Don't forget the single quotes `'` around `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Your line should be: `include "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/build/ChromePhp.php";`

Answer (score 4):

You are using `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` inside of singly quoted string, so the include path is that literal string.  You probably want:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/build/ChromePhp.php';
```

Your error message should have clued you in to this, as it shows the literal path that is being used for the include.